# PhpStorm does not see the folder in the directory

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, ubuntu-19.04

For some unknown reason, PhpStorm shows an empty folder. But in the file structure, like other IDEs, everything is visible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide details: folder name, screenshots of how it looks in PhpStorm (ideally whole IDE window so it may show some other details) and other IDEs; file system.

Comment: I update this qwestion

Comment: If you click on "Refresh" button on first screenshot (Open Project dialog in PhpStorm), will it work? Is that a symlink/mount point of some kind? Of so -- will it work if you open the actual folder directly (not symlinked path)? Will it work if you rename that folder so some another name (that would not contain "test" in it)? Other than that: please check idea.log folder for possible hints/exceptions (I'm a Windows user so may be missing some Linux nuances)

Comment: Is are real folder. If you click update, nothing will happen.

Comment: Well, if nothing interesting in the `idea.log` file (`Help | Show Log in...`) then consider contacting PhpStorm support team: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731 . I'm not a Linux user and cannot think of any other possible reasons that may be causing it. Support known more (have their knowledge base) and will figure that from your logs and other detailed description that you can provide there.